# How to build a Neural Network in Keras using a custom loss function with datapoint-specific weight?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function, loss

I want to train a Neural Network for a classification task in Keras using a TensorFlow backend with a custom loss function.  In my loss, I want to give different weights to different training examples. I have some datapoints I consider important and some I do not consider as important. I want my loss function to take this into account and punish errors in important examples more than in less important ones.

I have already built my model:

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(16,))
hidden_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(input)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax')(hidden_layer_1)
model  = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss(input), optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True, metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(), 'acc'])
```

and the currrent state of my loss function is:

```
def custom_loss(input):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return ...
    return loss
```

I'm struggling with implementing the loss function in the way I explained above, mainly because I don't exactly know what input, y_pred and y_true are (KerasTensors, I know - but what is the content? And is it for one training example only or for the whole batch?). I'd appreciate help with

1. printing out the values of input, y_true and y_pred
2. converting the input value to a numpy ndarray ([1,3,7] for example) so I can use the array to look up my weight for this specific training data point
3. once I have my weigth as a number (0.5 for example), how do I implement the computation of the loss function in Keras? My loss for one training exaple should be 0 if the classification was correct and weight if it was incorrect.

Comment: what's the custom loss you would like to use ?

Comment: I want to have 0 loss for a correcly classified training example and some sort of weight for an incorrectly classified one. Let's say my weight array is w=[0.2,1.0,0.0] and all of my examples were misclassified. Then my overall loss should be 0.2+1 = 1.2

Comment: Is there a solution for this?